# How to express this $\sin^8{\frac{2\pi}{7}}\sin^7{\frac{3\pi}{7}}$ in terms of $\sin{\frac{\pi}{7}}$,$\sin{\frac{2\pi}{7}}$,$\sin{\frac{3\pi}{7}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to find the way to express this expression: $$\sin^8{\frac{2\pi}{7}}\sin^7{\frac{3\pi}{7}}$$ in terms of $\sin{\frac{\pi}{7}}$,$\sin{\frac{2\pi}{7}}$,$\sin{\frac{3\pi}{7}}$

W.A gives the result which i want is:$$\frac{49(10\sin{\frac{\pi}{7}}+22\sin{\frac{3\pi}{7}}+17\sin{\frac{2\pi}{7}})}{16384}$$

I have no idea how to arrive this result which is given by W.A

I tried to reduce the 8 exponent of sine, but it will be long. I need some helps or hints from everyone. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you know about the complex representation of the sine?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, i know, you mean use complex form and binomial theorem?

Comment: Yes, along with the unit root properties.

Comment: But with the complex representation of the sine and using roots of unity, don't you also need the complementary cosine? Otherwise you just get a *huge* binomial since you can't use deMoivre's formula...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure expanding it out is a terrible way to go actually, especially with some shortcuts. Here, hold my root beer.

Let $x = \frac{\pi}{7}$ just so we don't have to type that over and over. The big shortcut is this:

$$
\begin{array}{l l l l i}
\sin x &= \sin 6x &= -\sin 8x &= -\sin 13x &= -\sin (-x)\\
\sin 2x &= \sin 5x &= -\sin 9x &= -\sin 12x &= -\sin (-2x)\\
\sin 3x &= \sin 4x &= -\sin 10x &= -\sin 11x &= -\sin (-3x)
\end{array}
$$

In other words, $\sin \frac{k\pi}{7}$ can always be converted to $\pm \sin \frac{\pi}{7}, \pm \sin \frac{2\pi}{7}$, or $\pm \sin \frac{3\pi}{7}$. There are similar conversions for cosine, but I won't show a large table; you can figure it out using identities.

Expanding the powers:

$$
\begin{align}
\sin^7 \left(3x\right) &= \textstyle \frac{1}{64}\displaystyle \left(35\sin 3x - 21 \sin 9x + 7 \sin 15x - \sin 21x\right) \\
&= \textstyle \frac{1}{64}\displaystyle \left(35\sin 3x + 21 \sin 2x + 7 \sin x \right) \\
&= \textstyle \frac{7}{64}\displaystyle \left(5\sin 3x + 3 \sin 2x + \sin x \right) \\
\sin^8 \left(2x\right) &= \textstyle \frac{1}{128}\displaystyle \left(35 - 56\cos 4x + 28 \cos 8x - 8 \cos 12x + \cos 16x\right) \\
&= \textstyle \frac{1}{128}\displaystyle \left(35 + 56\cos 3x - 28 \cos x - 7 \cos 2x\right) \\
&= \textstyle \frac{7}{128}\displaystyle \left(5 + 8\cos 3x - 4 \cos x - \cos 2x\right) \\
\sin^8 \left(2x\right)\cdot \sin^7 \left(3x\right) &= \textstyle \frac{49}{2^{13}}\displaystyle \left(5\sin 3x + 3 \sin 2x + \sin x \right) \left(5 + 8\cos 3x -  \cos 2x - 4 \cos x \right)
\end{align}
$$

It's tempting to convert those cosines to sines by applying phase shifts now, but we're going to wait. Why? First, well, consider what we subtract $2x$ or $3x$ from to get those shifts. (Actually think about it, I mean. I'll leave the answer as an exercise.) Second, look at what we have to multiply. Every term will have the form $c \sin a$ or $c \sin a \cdot \cos b$, and:

$$\sin a \cdot \cos b = \textstyle\frac12\displaystyle \left(\sin\left(a+b \right) + \sin\left(a-b \right)\right)$$

Having factored out $C_0 = \frac{49}{2^{13}}$, the arithmetic is easy-ish from here. Take a deep breath!

$$
\begin{align}
\sin^8(2x) \cdot \sin^7(3x) = C_0 &[ (25\sin 3x + 15 \sin 2x + 5 \sin x) \\
+&(20 \sin 3x \cos 3x + 12 \sin 2x \cos 3x + 4 \sin x \cos 3x) \\
-&(\textstyle\frac52\displaystyle \sin 3x \cos 2x + \textstyle\frac32\displaystyle \sin 2x \cos 2x + \textstyle\frac12\displaystyle \sin x \cos 2x) \\
-&(10 \sin 3x \cos x + 6 \sin 2x \cos x + 2 \sin x \cos x) ]
\\
\end{align}
$$

Using the table above, the fact that $\sin (-x) = - \sin x$, and the fact that $\sin 7x = \sin 0 = 0$, we can gather:

$$
\begin{align}
&=C_0 ( 25\sin 3x + 15 \sin 2x + 5 \sin x \\
&+ 20 \sin x + 12 \sin 2x - 12 \sin x + 4 \sin 3x - 4 \sin 2x \\
&- \textstyle\frac52\displaystyle \sin 2x - \textstyle\frac52\displaystyle \sin x - \textstyle\frac32\displaystyle \sin 3x - \textstyle\frac12\displaystyle \sin 3x + \textstyle\frac12\displaystyle\sin x \\
&- 10 \sin 3x - 10\sin 2x - 6 \sin 3x - 6 \sin x - 2 \sin 2x) \\
&= C_0(5 \sin x + \textstyle\frac{17}{2}\displaystyle \sin 2x +11 \sin 3x) = \textstyle\frac{49}{2^{14}}\displaystyle(10 \sin x + 17 \sin 2x +22 \sin 3x)
\end{align}
$$

Finally, reversing our very first substitution, we have:

$$\sin^8 \left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right) \sin^7 \left(\frac{3\pi}{7}\right)  =\frac{49}{2^{14}} \left(10 \sin \frac{\pi}{7} + 17 \sin \frac{2\pi}{7} +22 \sin \frac{3\pi}{7}\right)$$

which is the result you obtained from WA.

Answer (score 2):

[The usual boaring but useful technique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identit%C3%A9_trigonom%C3%A9trique#Lin%C3%A9arisation) (using Euler's formulas and the binomial coefficient theorem) [gives you](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor+sin%5E8%282x%29sin%5E7%283x%29) $\sin^8(2x)\sin^7(3x)=$
$$\frac1{2^{14}}\left(\begin{align}&1365\sin x+2226\sin(3x)+195\sin(5x)-1743\sin(7x)\\&-1182\sin(9x)
+588\sin(11x)+1113\sin(13x)+210\sin(15x)\\&-532\sin(17x)-357\sin(19x)+98\sin(21x)+196\sin(23x)+35\sin(25x)\\&-56\sin(27x)-28\sin(29x)+7\sin(31x)+8\sin(33x)-\sin(37x)\end{align}\right).$$
For $x=\frac\pi7$, using $\sin((7k+j)x)=(-1)^k\sin(jx)$ ($\forall k,j\in\mathbb Z$) and imparity of $\sin$, this simplifies to $\sin^8(2x)\sin^7(3x)=$
$$\frac1{2^{14}}\left(\begin{align}&1365\sin x+2226\sin(3x)+195\sin(2x)\\&+1182\sin(2x)
-588\sin(3x)-1113\sin x+210\sin x\\&-532\sin(3x)-357\sin(2x)-196\sin(2x)-35\sin(3x)\\&+56\sin x-28\sin x+7\sin(3x)+8\sin(2x)+\sin(2x)\end{align}\right)$$$$
=\frac1{2^{14}}\left(490\sin x+833\sin(2x)+1078\sin(3x)\right)
$$$$
=\frac{49}{2^{14}}\left(10\sin x+17\sin(2x)+22\sin(3x)\right).
$$

Comment: Is there a shortcut for the first part where you used WA? If not, writing out and multiplying the two expansions in terms of $\pm e^{\pm kix}$ seems like a ton of work left out, especially multiplying the expansions.

Comment: @EricSnyder admittedly much work, but absolutely trickless once you know the recipe,  hence not worth typing.

Comment: The two expansions are quite short. The big deal is multiplying them. If s.o. really wants to train, better reduce $k$ in the $e^{\pm kix}$'s in the two expansions *before* multiplying them.

Comment: Hah, an excellent point!